# remove everything except lines with % and remove the %

Tags: python, python-3.x, text

example:

```
1
Yuumi
78.57%
2075
1956
0.64
62.8
Thresh
77.59%
1079
917
0.83
19.3
Braum
76.00%
1868
1315
1.44
38.0
```

i want it to be:

```
78.57
77.59
76.00
```

(the numbers with the %)

tried looking in forums and use readlines from a file and stuff but im a beginner and couldn't make it work so yea
in python, thanks in advance

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
with open('path/to/the/file') as fd:
    for line in fd:
        if '%' in line:
            print(line.strip().replace('%', ''))
```

or you can do it in shell:

```
grep "%" filename | sed 's/%//g' >newfile
```

Comment: Thank you very much

Comment: This answer is explicit, not at all clever, and boring. I love it. That's the kind of code I want to debug at 2AM when things are broken.

Comment: @KirkStrauser another amazing feature of that code is that it never breaks, so nobody will ever had a need to debug it at 2am...

Answer (score 1):

You can use [regular expressions](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.search):

```
import re

with open("file.txt") as f:
    for line in f:
        r = re.search(r'(\d+(\.[\d]+)?)%', line)
        if r:
            print(r.group(1))
```

And on your sample data this gives:

```
78.57
77.59
76.00
```

---

[regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/VLwGax/2)

Answer (score -1):

Let's say you have read all your inputs into a list. You could try this.

```
inp = ['1', 'Yuumi', '78.59%', ...]
out = [float(a.remove('%')) for a in inp if '%' in a]
```

You can get all your inputs from a file into a list if you do

```
with open('my_file.txt') as file:
    inp = file.read.splitlines()
```